# Missing point symbols

Tags: qgis

In a point layer, QGIS is rendering the label but not the symbol and I cannot see how to rectify this. In another point layer in the same project both the symbol and the label are rendering correctly. I am using 3.16 Hannover.

---

Two screen shots with the map layer switched on and off.
[image: This is the screen shot with the map layer on]

[image: This is the screen shot with the map layer off. Now the + symbol can be seen]

Comment: Without wishing to be patronising, is your point layer beneath another layer? (a basemap, for example) - it happens to us all at some point.

Comment: Thank you, no offence taken. I forgot to add that when the map layer is turned off the symbol and label are both rendered. So it is as if the label and symbol are split across different layers.

Comment: It looks like you indeed have two layers - otherwise the symbol could not appear when you turn off the layer. Can you show a screenshot or share project + data? Otherwise, it's just guesswork

Comment: I don't know how to share screen shots on this site. I would be happy to show my problem to a willing helper using Zoom.

Comment: You can paste an image from your clipboard into your question body and it will give you a confirmation dialog asking you if you want to add a picture.

Comment: On the images you posted, I can't recognize the problem you describe... Please be a bit more precise and tell us exactly what you do and where the problem appears.

Comment: @Babel, it seems to be that the cross symbol for the chapels layer does not appear when the raster layer is visible, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: You might change your chapel symbol in a simple way, such as by changing the cross color to red or increasing the symbol size quite a bit, to see if the symbol is merely being lost in the maze of gray lines from the base map

Comment: Indeed - your 2nd screenshot clearly shows that the symbol is there, so just not visible with the raster background. Please delete your answer and paste the images above by editing your initial post

Comment: Did you try changing the symbol as noted above? Can you share the project + data?

Comment: I have got round the problem by removing the map layer, then reloading it into the project. Clearly there is something a bit flaky here but pleased I have managed to circumvent it. Apologies again for posting things in the wrong place. Consequently, I have also found that if the point layer is loaded into a project before the map the symbols and labelling render correctly. Someone seems to have kindly sorted that out for me.